# How to print a DataGrid in WPF, not a DataGridView

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, datagrid, system.drawing

"InvokePaint" is displaying error, **"this"** of the **InvokePaint**  method is supposed to be a class, but i don't know which class it should be, any help will be appreciated.

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from CallRegister", data.getCon());
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("Call Reciept");
                da.Fill(dt);
                DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
                dg.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
                System.Drawing.Size m = new System.Drawing.Size((int)dg.Width, (int)dg.Height);

                System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs myPaintArgs = new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs(e.Graphics, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0),m));
                this.InvokePaint(dg, myPaintArgs);
```

Comment: You should consider removing unnecessary code, and post a simple example that users on SO can inspect and try to help you. In your post, you can easily get rid of SqlDataAdapter or anything related to that, create a xaml that contains sample data for the DataGrid you want to use as an example, and show the simple outline of the class and the method that contains the call to "this.InvokePaint(...)". Doing these would help you elicit answers - the question as posed is not very well written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method can be called only from `WindowsForms` control [as MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokepaint(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Raises the Paint event for the specified control. Namespace:
>   System.Windows.Forms Assembly:  System.Windows.Forms (in
>   System.Windows.Forms.dll)

So this code should be called from hosted `WinForms` control inside WPF project:

```
this.InvokePaint((dg, myPaintArgs);
```

**Update. To print Datagrid:**

XAML:

```
<DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Persons, Mode=TwoWay}" Name="dataGrid"/>
<Button Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click" Content="Print DataGrid"/>
```

Code behind:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
   var pd = new PrintDialog();
   var result = pd.ShowDialog();
   if (result.HasValue && result.Value)
      pd.PrintVisual(dataGrid, "My WPF printing a DataGrid");
}
```

Comment: I am trying to print a datagrid(which collects information from a database table) into paper, when i checked online, that is the code, i saw. Any help or ideas?

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But, i want to try to put in other information on the printed page, how would i do it.

Comment: @EdwardsMoses it is really better to ask new question about adding new data to existed data of datagrid. Cause it provides consistency and clearness of question.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the `DataGrid` for each Item. Append strings using the `StringBuilder`, instantiate `FlowDocument` and `Paragraph` objects.

Add string created from `StringBuilder` to `Paragraph` and add `Paragraph` to `FlowDocument`. Print `FlowDocument` (cast to `IDocumentPaginatorSource`) using the `PrintDialog` :)

```
StringBuilder sbClipboardStringText = new StringBuilder();
foreach (object dataItem in dgvDataGridView.Items)
{
    var drvDataRowView = dataItem as DataRowView;

    string var2 = (string)drvDataRowView["Var2"];
    int var3 = (int)drvDataRowView["Var3"];

    sbClipboardStringText.AppendFormat("{0} \t {1}\n", var2.Trim(), var3);
}
string result = sbClipboardStringText.ToString();

Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.Margin = new Thickness(50);

p.Inlines.Add(result);
flowDocument.Blocks.Add(p);

PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
if (pd.ShowDialog() != true) return;

flowDocument.PageHeight = pd.PrintableAreaHeight;
flowDocument.PageWidth = pd.PrintableAreaWidth;

IDocumentPaginatorSource idocument = flowDocument as IDocumentPaginatorSource;

pd.PrintDocument(idocument.DocumentPaginator, "Printing Flow Document...");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
 printDialog.PrintVisual(dataGrid, "Print Grid");
```